# How to add a point to sensor_msgs::PointCloud2?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, 2dlaserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I declare a point as

`Eigen::Vector2f point;`

However, I cannot add this point  to my PointCloud2 with this code:

`sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 filteredPoints;`

`filteredPoints.data.push_back(point);`

The issue is the data is a type of `std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>`. The eror shows clearly: `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::push_back(Eigen::Vector2f&)`
I never work with such a vector type with allocator as the second template.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363493/how-to-add-a-point-to-sensor_msgs::pointcloud2?/) by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2020-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is saying that you can't just use an Eigen::Vector2f to add a point to a pointcloud2. See [this example](https://answers.ros.org/question/312587/generate-and-publish-pointcloud2-in-ros2/) for a use case of generating a point cloud and then publishing it.

As I understand it the best practice is that you process the data using the [pcl library](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl), and then after you have made the pointcloud you convert it to the ROS msg pointcloud2 and then publish it.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-15**:
Thank you @jackB! But how can I integrate ros_pcl in an existing project in ros-melodic? I got an error msg: `No such file or directory #include <pcl/conversions.h>`, even I added `pcl_conversions` in my CMakeLists.txt. It seems I need to download the package too.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-15**:
You should open another, separate question, with more detail and context so that someone can help you solve it. Glad I could help get you started in the right direction.

**Comment by [wiyogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/60646/wiyogo/) on 2020-10-16**:
Thanks @JackB. This is my new question https://answers.ros.org/question/363532/how-to-integrate-pcl-library-into-an-existing-project/